# How to read out NodeJS form Data and write to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, mongoose

I've created a simple dynamic single page form which renders a number of fields based on x number of people. I've used the extended setting in the body parser to submit nested objects in my html.

When I console log req.body I get this:

```
    {
    user: {
        '10': {
            attending: '1',
            dietaryRequirements: 'None'
        },
        '11': {
            attending: '0',
            dietaryRequirements: 'Not Applicable'
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the easiest way to read out the ID (10 & 11) and write the attending and dietary requirement fields to MongoDB.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using mongoose as orm with express?

Comment: Yes i'm using Mongoose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to define a Schema first of all.

```
//this is ../models/user.model file

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//Define user model schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    attending: { type: Number, required: true },
    dietaryRequirements: String,
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
const User= mongoose.model('users', userSchema );
module.exports = User;
```

Then, you have got user as an object so you need to insert data into array
as objects.This each object need to mach to Schema that you defined. when you add user objects to array you can easily call mongoose `insertMany()` method that came from User Schema.

```
const User= require('../models/user.model');
const { user } = req.body;
console.log(user );
let userItems= Object.keys(user).map(userItem => {
         return {
               _id: userItem,
               attending: user[userItem ].attending,
               dietaryRequirements: user[userItem ].dietaryRequirements,
          }
 });
 try {
      await User.insertMany(userItems);

      res.status(200).json({ status: true });
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
```

this `User.insertMany(userItems)` method 'await' until all data save in mongo db hence you have to use 'async' keyword in express router.

For more [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-express/)

**update multiple random users**

Here you can use asynchronous loop then code will be fast.

```
let updateResponces = await Promise.all(userItems.map(user=>{
   User.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { attending: 'true'});
});
```

Comment: Almost perfect, how would I go about updating the records. I've tried User.updateMany({_id: userItems._id},  { "$set": { "attending": "true" } }, ); but it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks!

Comment: you want to set 'attending' to specific people (more than one) right?

Comment: Yes correct. I want to update multiple records to show whether or not they're attending. I also changed the values to true or false for attending so I can update a boolean type in MongoDB.

Comment: @CameronRose in this case you can not use updateMany because you don't have reference to update each user. for example you can updateMany with all people who already attending true. Got it? So in your case there is no reference but random users. Hence you can use a loop for this. If you like to that approach I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah if you don't mind could you update your answer to this please! :)